# Use a single AsyncTask(background thread) for coding performance

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

> Code is running absolutely fine. But it is slow and sometime shows ANR. I want a single thread or AsyncTask which is running continuosly and handles imagebrightness values also. I cannot create multiple AsyncTask because (they all do the same operation) .

I simply have to get the `YUV byte code` and `convert it to bitmap` and set it to my `Activity View`.

```
private android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback()
    {
        public void onPreviewFrame(final byte abyte0[] , Camera camera)
        {       
            int[] rgbData =  YuvUtils.myDecodeGreyscale(abyteData, widthPreview, heightPreview, imageBrightness, nonGreencolorOffset, greenColorOffset); 

            editedBitmap.setPixels(rgbData, 0, widthPreview, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview);

            if(MainActivity2.cameraId==CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            {   
                matrix.setRotate(270F);
            }
            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(editedBitmap, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview, matrix, true);

            //above all methods should be call on background Thread.
            MainActivity2.drawView.setBitmapToDraw(finalBitmap);//only this statement should be use in Main Thread
        }
    };
```

**What have i tried**

I have created a new AsyncTask on Each previewFrame() call. It hangs the Device. I have also tried to do this using Thread but having same problem.

I simply want my code to execute on seperate background thread which is connected with my Activity like bound Service. 
I also Thread.sleep to overcome ANR. but It stops the UI .

```
try
{
   Thread.sleep(1L);

}
catch (InterruptedException interruptedexception)
{
    interruptedexception.printStackTrace();
}
```

> onPreviewFrame calls three times in a second. I want to do the operation one or two times in a seconds to show continuous CameraPreview. Can someOne suggest me how can i achieve this.

**What are my idea.**

1. I should sleep the Thread for half second each time because i don't
   want to set the Preview thrice in a second.
2. I should use static Variable or Create an inner AsyncTask to handle
   these operation.

**AsyncTask**

```
public class CameraPreviewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public static int cameraId;
    public static boolean isRunning;
    public Context ctx;
    public byte[] data;
    public boolean dataAvailable;
    private Bitmap editedBitmap;
    private Bitmap finalBitmap;
    private int green;
    public double greenColorOffset;
    private int heightPreview;
    private int widthPreview;
    public int imageBrightness=70;
    private int iterator;
    private int iteratorLimit;
    int j;
    private Matrix matrix;
    public double nonGreencolorOffset=30;
    private int nongreen=20;
    private int p;
    private int[] pixels_preview;
    public boolean saveCurrentFrame;
    public boolean workingOnData;

    public CameraPreviewTask(final Context ctx, final int widthPreview, final int heightPreview)
    {
        saveCurrentFrame = false;
        dataAvailable = false;
        workingOnData = false;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.widthPreview = widthPreview;
        this.heightPreview = heightPreview;
        iteratorLimit = widthPreview * heightPreview;
        pixels_preview = new int[iteratorLimit];
        editedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthPreview, heightPreview, Config.ARGB_8888);
        (matrix = new Matrix()).postRotate(90.0f);
        CameraPreviewTask.isRunning = true;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... array) 
    {
        while (CameraPreviewTask.isRunning) 
        {
            try 
            {
                while (!dataAvailable) 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1L);
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) 
            {
                Log.e("EditorWorker", "Error while waiting for data =" + ex.getMessage());
            }

            try 
            {
                workingOnData = true;

                int[] rgbData =  YuvUtils.myDecodeGreyscale(data, widthPreview, heightPreview, imageBrightness, nonGreencolorOffset, greenColorOffset); 

                editedBitmap.setPixels(rgbData, 0, widthPreview, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview);

                if(MainActivity2.cameraId==CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                {   
                    matrix.setRotate(270F);
                }

                finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(editedBitmap, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview, matrix, true);

                publishProgress((Void[])new Void[0]);

                workingOnData = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex2) 
            {
                Log.e("Error", ex2.getMessage() + "");
            }
            finally 
            {
                workingOnData = false;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... array) 
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate((Void[])array);

        MainActivity2.drawView.setBitmapToDraw(finalBitmap);

        if (saveCurrentFrame) 
        {
            saveCurrentFrame = false;

            new BitmapSaver(ctx, finalBitmap).start();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    public void start()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        {
            executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new Void[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            execute(new Void[0]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i can explain that device hangs because it creates 10's or even 100's of threads or asyncTasks so that makes very large load on the device and may consume all available heap-memory... all i can think of now is mixing a none-realtime processing with skipping some frames, it may need some tuning until you reach a good result? may be ... just a thought

Comment: It seems like you are trying to reinvent IntentService?

Comment: So you suggest I should use IntentService. but how can I also set SeekBar value while it is running

Comment: Where is your AsyncTask?

Comment: I have include my AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea that may be relaized in different ways, somebody please correct me if I'm creating a horrible memory leak or completely ignoring thread-safety somewhere. I'm always counting on variables being written by only one thread.

In your MainActivity, make a Handler/Runnable combo and just let it update your view every say....40ms:

```
MainActivity extends Activity{ //beware pseudo code
    Bitmap finalBitmap;
    Handler viewHandler; //android.os.Handler, not the java one
    boolean camIsRunning = false;
    AtomicBoolean newBitmap = false;
    Camera myCamera;
    byte aByte[];

    Runnable updateView = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            if(camIsRunning){
                drawView.setBitmapToDraw(finalBitmap);
                alsoUpdateSeekbarAndStuffIMayHaveForgotten(); //<- edit
                viewHandler.postDelayed(updateView, 40);
            }
        }
    };

    onCreate(...){ //beware pdeudo code again
        initYourStuff(); //whatever
        viewHandler = new Handler();
        finalBitmap = initBitmap(); //not sure how you initialize/start your bitmap handling, just make sure to draw your bitmap only after there is one, so put a placeholder here until the cam is running.
        startCamera(); //also triggers camIsRunning;
        //After there is a bitmap and the camera is running  and actually every time you start up your camera:
        viewHandler.post(updateView);
        new BitmapOperator().start();
    }

    class BitmapOperator extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            while(camIsRunning){
                if(newBitmap.weakCompareAndSet(true, false)) //if there is a new bitmap, reset to false and process.
                    processBitmap(aByte[], camera); //convert here
            }
        }
    }
private android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback()
{
    public void onPreviewFrame(final byte abyte0[] , Camera camera)
    {       
        aByte[] = abyte0[];
        myCamera = camera;
        newBitmap.set(true); //Atomic for thread safety because I'm too lazy to sync stuff manually for just this one variable.
    }
};
}
```